# How to make datepicker empty as default

Tags: react-native

I use this code to show `datepicker`, but my problem is how to make empty as default. I try to change the initial value to null but the `datepicker` like a disable.

```js
{
  getFieldDecorator("dob", {
    rules: [genRequiredError("Date of Birth")],
    initialValue: userData.dob
  })(
    <DatePicker
      disabledDate={disabledKids}
      format="MM-DD-YYYY"
      placeholder="Select Date of Birth"
    />
  );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which module are you using the DatePicker component from?

Comment: @FatihAktaş I use this : import { DatePicker } from "antd";

Comment: You should consider editing your react-native tag as this question is not directly related to react-native. If you use the DatePicker from React-Native you can use the ‘date’ prop that Malik mentioned and initiate the DatePicker component with any Date() object you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass local state like `date={this.state.date}` and make local state empty in constructor

Comment: i can't use constructor because the datepicker is not in class